# mlmodel converted from coremltools4.0 is much slower than mlmodel converted from tfcoreml

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, coremltools

I have designed a simple network using tensorflow 1.15, and converted it to mlmodels using tfcoreml and coremltools4.0. I have tested them on iPhoneXS with system version ios13.5.1, and found that the mlmodel converted from coremltools4.0 is much slower than from tfcoreml.

The original network in tensorflow is as following:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 1000, 1000, 4], name="input")
    y = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 4, 1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    output_names = [y.op.name]
```

1. Converting to mlmodel using tfcoreml

```
# using tfcoreml
coreml_save_tfcoreml_file = model_dir + "/debug_tfcoreml.mlmodel"
tfcoreml.convert(tf_model_path=frozen_graph_file,
                    mlmodel_path=coreml_save_tfcoreml_file,
                    output_feature_names=["conv2d/Relu:0"],  # name of the output tensor (appended by ":0")
                    input_name_shape_dict={"input": [1, 1000, 1000, 4]},  # input tensor[1, height, width, channel]
                    minimum_ios_deployment_target='12')
```

[image]

2. Converting mlmodel using coremltools4.0:

```
coreml_save_coremltools_file = model_dir + "/debug_coremltools.mlmodel"
mlmodel = ct.convert(frozen_graph_file, source='tensorflow')
mlmodel.save(coreml_save_coremltools_file)
```

[image]

I tested both mlmodels on the same iPhoneXS device, and #2 takes much more time than #1, whether on cpu and cpu+gpu or using ANE.

To confirm the mlmodel running on ANE, then I inserted 10 1x1 convolution layers in the network to add the calculated amount. And they all indeed runs on ANE and the time costs are (ALL < CpuAndGpu < CpuOnly). But #2 still takes much more time than #1, about 2x slower.

It seems that coremltools4.0 changes the data type from HWC to CHW format by inserting a **transpose** layer. But tf2coreml accepts CHW format directly.

How can I remove the transpose layer in coremltools4.0's convertation to verify whether this layer is the reason causing performance degeneration?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah，I think that I have found the reason. I have used "MLModel Surgery" to modify the mlmodel, removing the two transpose layers, and modifing the input shape and output shape info to NCHW format. Then the performace using coretools4.0 is same with tfcoreml. :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue when trying to convert the u2net model to an ML. Loading the ML model is very slow (30seconds). I'm using this guide: https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/u2net-to-coreml-machine-learning-segmentation-on-iphone-eac0c721d67b. What should I change when converting?